# Проблема с ответом в Django + Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

Добрые люди, нужна Ваша помощь. Ситуация такая (и очень страшная):

- Стек: Django + Postgres
- Идет поисковый API-запрос к моему приложению, в ответе на который должен быть JSON с найденными данными

**И вот в чем проблема.**
В зависимости от значения флага Debug, приходят разные ответы. Если False -пустой ответ, если True - с данными.

- Настроено все так, что независимо от флага запрос идет к одной и той
  же базе, от одного и того же пользователя БД.
- Так как это API и запрос делается с помощью url-а, исключается вина
  фронта.

  В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: параметры запросов одинаковые, пользователь внутри приложения - тоже. Все одинаковое. Я вообще чудом увидел,что ответ меняется, в зависимости от Debug

Comment: Нам нужен ваш код, мы ведь не экстрасенсы тут сидим :) Далее сможем ответить почему так происходит

Comment: Спасибо) а код чего Вам сможет помочь? Просто это самая обычная view с запросом к БД. без декораторов даже. Файл настроек тоже ничего не содержит, что смогло бы повлиять. Я просто думал,может существует объяснение на уровне инструментов?

Comment: Например, может тот же postgres что-то кеширует для ускорения запросов и в эту тему копать или даже не знаю. Если проблема в коде, то я тогда попробую сам разобраться =)
Потому что при таком раскладе это слишком частный случай и не несет ценности для сообщества

Comment: Нет, постгрес также как и любая другая база данных работает в джанго.. Проблема в коде, может даже в сеттинге Джанго, ну или же во View.. Нужно дебажить, искать